# What is the name of the property $x^m=x$ when $x$ is in a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, definition

I have been doing problems in Atiyah & MacDonald's Introduction to Commutative Algebra, and in problem 1.6 it asks to assume the existence of an idempotent element in an ideal whenever the ideal does not lie inside the nilradical. I could have sworn the definition of idempotent was as in the title, but after some investigation, idempotence seems to be reserved for the case where $m=2$.

This sort of blunder could have set me astray, as for example, the hypothesis in problem 1.6 seems to become considerably weaker. Luckily the weakened hypothesis did the job just fine for that problem, but I'd like to prevent future trouble by having a name for the general $m$.

So what is it? I have seen this property before, so I imagine it has been named somewhere, but I cannot seem to find one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_(algebra)

Comment: @A.Jiménez being torsion does not imply idempotence.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo thank you so much! I've heard whispers of the TOR functor before, but I have yet to know what it means. I guess I'll be getting plenty of experience with such elements!

Comment: In an integral domain $x^m=x$ for $x\neq 0$ is equivalent to $x^{m-1}=1$, that is, torsion element of the multiplicative group.

Comment: @lisyarus Does that mean in a ring that isn't an integral domain, that torsion might not imply the property?

Comment: @QTHalfTau No, it works in opposite direction. In any ring torsion $x^{m-1}=1$ implies your condition $x^m=x$, but the opposite may be false, if the ring is not a PID. For an example take the ring of matrices, where projections are idempotent but not torsion.

Comment: Err yes, I intended to ask the converse of what I actually asked. So I guess if the ring isn't nice enough, this property can't be called torsion. :/

Oh well, I guess I can refer to it as $m$-idempotence or something similar. It's a shame there doesn't seem to be a name for it.

Comment: @lisyarus Most rings only have multiplicative monoids, not groups ;)

Comment: @rschwieb under the term "multiplicative group" I mean the group of units, of course.

Comment: @QTHalfTau *Usually* there is a name for every useful thing. If something lacks a name, this is probably due to it being less useful :)

Comment: @lisyarus oh, I see at the start of the comment you began with a power of X being 1. Initially I thought you were speaking in general of the whole multiplicative monoid. Sorry